# run jar-file on startup linux

Tags: linux, bash, jar

I've used a standard bash-startup script for autostarting my Teamspeak Server - which works perfectly. Now I've done the same for the JTS3 Server Mod, problem: It's a `.jar`-file and doesn't start. If I run the `.jar`/startscript manually it works just fine.

Here's the script in `/etc/init.d/`

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             jts3servermod
# Required-Start:       $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:        $local_fs $network
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Description:          JTS3 Server Mod
### END INIT INFO
 

# INIT Script by www.SysADMINsLife.com
######################################
# Customize values for your needs: "User"; "DIR"

USER="ts"
DIR="/home/ts/JTS3ServerMod"
 
###### Teamspeak 3 server start/stop script ######
 
case "$1" in
start)
su $USER -c "${DIR}/jts3servermod_startscript.sh start"
;;
stop)
su $USER -c "${DIR}/jts3servermod_startscript.sh stop"
;;
restart)
su $USER -c "${DIR}/jts3servermod_startscript.sh restart"
;;
status)
su $USER -c "${DIR}/jts3servermod_startscript.sh status"
;;
*)
echo "Usage: {start|stop|restart|status}" >&2
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

of course it is linked in the `runlevel-folders` with `update-rc.d jts3servermod` defaults.

the servermod startscript (`jts3servermod_startscript.sh`) is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# JTS3ServerMod Linux start script
# Created by Stefan "Stefan1200" Martens
# The author of this script is not responsible for any damage or data loss!

JAVA_COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS="-mx30M"           # You can add java arguments here, like the -mx30M argument!
JTS3SERVERMOD_COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS=""  # You can add JTS3ServerMod arguments here, like the -config and -log argument!
BINARYPATH="$(pwd)"                      # This have to point to the JTS3ServerMod directory!

# Don't change the lines below, if you are not a sh script expert!
cd "${BINARYPATH}"
BINARYNAME="JTS3ServerMod.jar"
ROOTUID="0"

case "$1" in
        java)
                if which java >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                        echo "Java is already installed:"
                        java -version
                else
                        if [ "$(id -u)" -ne "$ROOTUID" ] ; then
                                echo "Start this script as root to start the automatic installation of the Java runtime environment."
                                echo "You can also read the system requirements of the JTS3ServerMod in the readme.txt file for a manual installation of the Java runtime environment."
                                exit 6
                        else
                                read -p "Do you wish to install the Java runtime environment? (y/n) " yn
                                case $yn in
                                        [Yy]* ) installJava; break;;
                                        * ) echo "Aborted!"; exit 6;;
                                esac
                        fi
                fi
        ;;
        start)
                if ! which java >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                        echo "The JTS3ServerMod needs the Java runtime environment installed to run!"
                        echo "Start this script with the java argument as root to start the automatic installation of the Java runtime environment:"
                        echo "$0 java"
                        echo "You can also read the system requirements of the JTS3ServerMod in the readme.txt file for a manual installation of the Java runtime environment."
                        exit 6
                fi
                if [ "$(id -u)" -eq "$ROOTUID" ] ; then
                        echo "For security reasons it is prefered not to run the JTS3ServerMod as root!"
                fi
                if [ -e jts3servermod.pid ]; then
if ( kill -0 $(cat jts3servermod.pid) 2> /dev/null ); then
                                echo "The JTS3ServerMod is already running, try restart or stop!"
                                exit 1
                        else
                                echo "jts3servermod.pid found, but no JTS3ServerMod running. Possibly your previously started JTS3ServerMod crashed!"
                                echo "Please view the logfile for details."
                                rm -f jts3servermod.pid
                        fi
                fi
                echo "Starting the JTS3ServerMod..."
                if [ -e "$BINARYNAME" ]; then
                        java ${JAVA_COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS} -jar ${BINARYNAME} ${JTS3SERVERMOD_COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS} > /dev/null &
                        PID=$!
                        ps -p ${PID} > /dev/null 2>&1
                        if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
                                echo "JTS3ServerMod could not start!"
                        else
                                echo $PID > jts3servermod.pid
                                echo "JTS3ServerMod started, for details please view the log file!"
                        fi
                else
                        echo "Could not find the file $BINARYNAME, aborting!"
                        exit 5
                fi
        ;;
        stop)
if [ -e jts3servermod.pid ]; then
                        echo -n "Stopping the JTS3ServerMod.."
                        if ( kill -TERM $(cat jts3servermod.pid) 2> /dev/null ); then
                                c=1
                                while [ "$c" -le 120 ]; do
                                        if ( kill -0 $(cat jts3servermod.pid) 2> /dev/null ); then
                                                echo -n "."
                                                sleep 1
                                        else
                                                break
                                        fi
                                        c=$(($c+1))
                                done
                        fi
                        if ( kill -0 $(cat jts3servermod.pid) 2> /dev/null ); then
                                echo "JTS3ServerMod is not shutting down cleanly - killing!"
                                kill -KILL $(cat jts3servermod.pid)
                        else
                                echo "done"
                        fi
                        rm -f jts3servermod.pid
                else
                        echo "No JTS3ServerMod running (jts3servermod.pid is missing)!"
                        exit 7
                fi
        ;;
        restart)
                $0 stop && $0 start || exit 1
        ;;
        status)
if [ -e jts3servermod.pid ]; then
                        if ( kill -0 $(cat jts3servermod.pid) 2> /dev/null ); then
                                echo "JTS3ServerMod is running!"
                        else
                                echo "JTS3ServerMod seems to have died!"
                        fi
                else
                        echo "No JTS3ServerMod running (jts3servermod.pid is missing)!"
                fi
        ;;
        *)
                echo "Usage: ${0} {start|stop|restart|status|java}"
                exit 2
esac
exit 0
```

I also tried to write an own simple script for only starting the jar and catching the pid and writing it into a file.
None of these scripts wanted to start my `.jar` file during the startup.

As you can see, the first script is a template for starting Teamspeak Servers during boot. I only replaced some stuff with my Server Mod paths and scripts and put into `/etc/init.d/` (`chmod 755` was executed of course).

Maybe some of you have other approaches to solve that strange circumstances.

Comment: Have you considered looking up cron?

Comment: What do you mean with looking up cron? The output of crontab -e? It's empty, on both users, root and ts (the user who starts the script).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the problem was solved in the meantime, but while experimenting with the same issue. I figured out that the script could not find the jar file. So I added:

```
#!/bin/sh
# JTS3ServerMod Linux start script
# Created by Stefan "Stefan1200" Martens
# The author of this script is not responsible for any damage or data loss!
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
...
```

At the beginning of the jts3servermod_startscript.sh to ensure that the "working directory" is correct.

BTW - My init script:
jts-bot

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             jts-bot
# Required-Start:       $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:        $local_fs $network
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Description:          JTS3-Bot for TeamSpeak
### END INIT INFO


USER="teamspeak"
DIR="/home/teamspeak/JTS3ServerMod"

###### JTS3ServerMod start/stop script ######

case "$1" in
start)
su $USER -c "${DIR}/jts3servermod_startscript.sh start"
;;
stop)
su $USER -c "${DIR}/jts3servermod_startscript.sh stop"
;;
restart)
su $USER -c "${DIR}/jts3servermod_startscript.sh restart"
;;
status)
su $USER -c "${DIR}/jts3servermod_startscript.sh status"
;;
*)
echo "Usage: -bash {start|stop|restart|status}" >&2
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```